# Center only the first segment of a line

Tags: html, css

I have a line of text that includes a name and an id code. I would like the name to be centered in the line and for the id code to sit immediately to the right of the centered name. Is this possible?

I thought the following code might work, but it didn't:

```
   .name-text{
      text-align: center;
   }


   <span class="name-text">Centered Name here</span> non-centered text here.
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You can't do it as a single line of text. You would need to have them be separate elements, and the `span` is not able to out run the surrounding text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try absolute positioning to take the right element out-of-flow:

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
.right {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="name-text">Centered Name here.</span>
  <span class="right">Non-centered text here.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot.